# Toast is unable to draw

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am creating one Broadcat receiver aplication. In that I am getting following error

```
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (MyPhoneCall, String, int)
```

Java code :

```
package com.example.myphonecall;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyPhoneCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @
    Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                String phoneNumber = extras
                    .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                //Log.w("MY_DEBUG_TAG", phoneNumber);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Getting Call from " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(context, "Getting Call from "+phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Use the context passed to  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

Comment: make static activity varialble used in toast.

Comment: Pass the context. You are passing the reference to MyPhoneCall which is extending BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Getting Call from "+phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `this` , pass `context` and it will resolve your issue.